# CodeIgniter - Model loaded but can't be used?

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoloader

Ok. So I am working on a website using CI. Here is the structure of my controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller
class User extends MY_Controller
class User_Model
```

So, I load the User_Model inside the constructor of the User controller. I know that it is loaded properly because I tried to print something from User_Model and it worked just fine. However, when I use one of the functions in the User_Model from User controller, it started giving me the error. This is the error I received:

> Undefined property: User::$User_Model

Anybody has any idea?

This is extended controller

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
      parent::Controller();
    }
}
```

This is the controller

```
class User extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('user_model');
      echo $this->user_model->validate_user('hartantothio');
    }
}
```

This is the User_model

```
class User_model extends Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::Model();
    }        
    public function validate_user($user, $pass = '') {
        return '123';
    }
}
```

Comment: can you paste your code in here? its hard to debug a problem with magic

Comment: I have editted my original post.

Comment: I've run into this problem as well: 
this did not solve it form me, but it was interesting to read:
http://grasshopperpebbles.com/codeigniter/codeigniter-call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object/

Comment: try $this->load->model('User_model', '', TRUE);

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
```

should read

```
$this->load->model('User_model');
```

Models names are case-sensitive!

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the function using the syntax, $this->User_Model->function_name()?

I also know that I've run into problems with case sensitivity as well in the past.

Comment: Yes.. This is what I do:
$this->load->model('User_Model');
echo $this->User_Model->validate_user($data['username']);

Giving me error on the second line.

Comment: should it be: $this->User_model->validate_user($data['username']);

Answer (score 0):

Well, by taking the MY_Controller and extends the User controller directly of the Controller, that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put `My_Controller` file? I put mine in `system/application/libraries` and don't have any problems with it. Also, I use PHP4 constructor way to write it, instead of `__constructor`:

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller {

  var $is_ajax_request = '';
  var $is_ajax_form = '';

  function MY_Controller()
  {
    parent::Controller();
    //initialize
    $this->is_ajax_request = ($this->input->server('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest');
    $this->is_ajax_form = ($this->input->post('ajax') == 'ajax');
    log_message('debug', "MY_Controller Class Initialized");
    //do extra stuffs here
    //...
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes. I put it in that folder as well. I have also used the old style constructor (same name as the class) and it still doesn't work. Hah... This is weird.

Comment: Uhm, I never put load code in constructor. I always do load model and call model's method in controller's method, such as `function index()`. My Controller's constructor is usually just call parent constructor.